# Preventing slow queries from exausting gunicorn worker pool

Tags: python, mysql, django, redis, gunicorn

Let's say that we have a rather typical Django web application:

- there is an Nginx in front of the app doing proxy stuff and serving
  static content
- there is gunicorn starting workers to handle Django requests
- there is Django-based web app doing all kinds of fun stuff
- there is a Redis server for sessions/cache
- there is a MySQL database serving queries from Django

Some URLs have basically just a rendered Django template with almost no queries, some pages incorporate some info from Redis. **But** there are a few pages that do some rather involved database queries, which can (after all possible optimizations) take several seconds to execute on MySQL side.

And here my problem - each time a gunicorn worker gets a request for such *heavy* URL it no longer serves other requests for a while - it just sits there idle waiting for the database to reply. If there are enough such queries then eventually all workers just sit idle and wait on the *heavy* URLs leaving none to serve the other, faster pages.

It there a way to either allow worker to do other work while it is waiting on a database reply? Or to somehow scale up worker pool in such situation (preferably without also scaling RAM usage and database connection count :))? At least is there a way to find out any statistics on how many workers are busy in a gunicorn pool and for how long each of them has been processing a request?

Comment: Have you tried using gunicorn's async worker type?

Comment: You might also want to post your database queries separately to Stackexchange, you might be surprised at some optimization you haven't thought of.

Comment: You might find my post at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/02/vertically-partitioning-python-web.html interesting. But then, because of not having a proper multithreading option, nor the ability to split apps vertically in one managed system, gunicorn is actually a poor choice for these sorts of optimisations.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way that might work in your case would be to increase the number of workers. The recommended number of workers is 2-4 x {NUM CPUS}. Depending on load and the type of requests to the site this might be enough.

The next step to look into if increasing number of workers isn't enough, would be to look into using async workers (docs about it [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html)). More detailed configuration options are described [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class). Note that depending on what type of async worker you choose to use, you will have to install either eventlet, gevent or tornado.